# Fhir Chaining Search Parameter Resource

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I want to search according to the id of the reference in the extension of the encounter reference in the ChargeItem resource.
Why is the search parameter I wrote not working?

Search Parameter;

```
{
  "resourceType": "SearchParameter",
  "id": "charge-item-encounter-reference",
  "url": "http://dev.genyazilim.com/fhir/SearchParameter/charge-item-encounter-reference",
  "name": "searchByEncounterReferenceChargeItem",
  "status": "active",
  "experimental": false,
  "date": "2024-02-12T00:00:00Z",
  "publisher": "İsmail Can Karataş",
  "description": "Search for Fee Items based on the reference of the referenced visit",
  "code": "encounter-reference",
  "base": [
    "ChargeItem"
  ],
  "type": "reference",
  "expression": "ChargeItem.encounter.resolve().extension('reference').value"
}
```

Comment: have the same issue. I am looking for answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty unusual for servers to support 'resolve()' as part of a search parameter definition.  Try using chaining, where you define two search parameters - one on ChargeItem.encounter, and one on Encounter extension.

Also, 'reference' isn't a valid URL for a root-level extension.  You need a full URI as the URL for extensions.  Only extension is nodes inside a complex extension.

Comment: I have a search parameter in the Encounter extension. But I don't know how to chain it

Comment: If the server supports chaining, you just tie the two search parameters together.  So `ChargeItem?encounter.someExtParam=foo`.  That presumes that the the server supports both the 'encounter' SearchParameter on Encounter, your custom SearchParameter on your extension on Encounter, and allows chaining of them.

Comment: I don't want to run `ChargeItem?encounter.someExtParam=foo` in this format. Because graphql doesn't support this search so I have to write search parameter. I want to run `ChargeItem?encounter-reference=123` in this format. What should be the correct Search Parameter resource?